# How to use a two digit year format (e.g. 13 instead of 2013) in Git log entries?

Tags: git, date, logging, format

I'm trying to maximize available space in each line of a customized Git log.

```
git log --date=short --pretty=format:"%ad ..."
```

is OK but gives dates in `yyyy-MM-dd` format (e.g. "2013-12-12").
With all the other stuff being logged on a limited length line, 2 characters becomes important!

Is there a way to output a two digit year (e.g. "12/12/13")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in, but you could just output the date as a raw time stamp (`--date=raw`) and do your own post-processing on the log output.  (Pipe the output to awk, python, perl, whatever, and have that replace the time-stamp values.)

Comment: Thanks for confirming there's nothing built-in - had suspected that might be the case but hoped it wasn't. Post-processing may be a step too far, will probably just live with this for now but thanks for the suggestion!